# How do I make ngDialog extend to full-screen?

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I need my dialog at full screen dimensions. I tried this:

```
/*CSS*/
.ngdialog-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gmap-display {
    margin: 0 0 -32px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.gmap-footer {
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: gray;
}

/*JS*/
ngDialog.open({
    template: 'templates/MapDialog.html',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-transparent',
    showClose: false,
    scope: $s
});

/*Template*/
<div class="gmap-display">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div class="gmap-footer">
    <a href="#" ng-click="closeThisDialog(0)">Cerrar</a>
</div>
```

Where the transparent theme is like `plain` except that no padding nor background-color in white are present.

What I see is a gray bar and a white bar overlapped: The lipsum text is above the gray bar with the close link. This means: The full-size specifications are being ignored.

How can I fix it so the dialog expands to fullscreen?

Comment: It's `height:100%` of the parent so you may need to make `html, body {height:100%}`.  But you would still be thrown off by the padding and margins so I would add a class to body when open to remove all of them.